# Assembly function to count the length of a given string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, strlen

I'm trying to understand the following function which I know is returning the length of a given string, but I cannot figure out the logic of lines 12 to 15. Why move eax to ebx and then add the argument that the function gets to ebx? and how the movzx of the first char of the string is working? it looks like I'm going to move the same character over and over again, what I'm missing here?

```
section .text
    global funcA
    
funcA:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax,-1
    push ebx
    
.L2:
    add eax, 1
    mov ebx, eax /* why? */
    add ebx, [ebp+8]/* why? */
    movzx   ebx, BYTE [ebx] /* why it is save the length*/
    test bl,bl 
    jne .L2
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: It's indexing the string as `string[ebx]` but the loop counter is in `eax`. Could be written better of course. It's looking for the zero byte at the end of the string.

Comment: Where did you get this inefficient and over-complicated `strlen` implementation?  There's no reason to recalculate the pointer into the string from the current length-count every iteration.  There's also no reason to use save/restore EBX instead of just using a call-clobbered register like EDX.  Is this supposed to be partially-optimized compiler output or something, like `gcc -Og`?  No, it's not GCC output; this is NASM syntax.  (No `.` in front of directives, and `byte` instead of `byte ptr`.)

Comment: @Jester I understand that the counter is eax and the but how is it that in each entrance to the L2 label I'm getting the next char in each movzx? where is the pointer decrement (to move to the next char)? because to me it looks like I always getting a pointer to the first char in line 13 over and over again

Comment: `add eax, 1` is the increment. Then `mov ebx, eax` transfers that to `ebx` and that is used for indexing.

Comment: @Jester thank you but I'm still not exactly understand how it is used for indexing? supoose I have the value 2 in ebx after line 12 on the third iteration, why the "add ebx, [ebp+8] will give me the third char? [the char in position 2]

Comment: `[ebp + 8]` is the address of the first char. Adding to that of course gives you following characters.

Comment: @Jester oh, ok I got it now! thank you very much!